# Change the background color of a previous UL

Tags: jquery, html, css, updatepanel

The following DIV is inside an update panel:

```
<div style="overflow: hidden; float: left; width: 31%; padding: 1%;">
    <ul class="tabs">
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">STEP #2</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="content">
        <div style="display: block;">
            <h4>To update the profile for every provider once the SQL job has been executed</h4>
            <div style="overflow: hidden; clear: both; padding: 0 0 20px 0;">
                <button onclick="__doPostBack('ctl00$CPHB$btnUpdateAP','')" id="co_AP" type="button" class="btnAll btnUpdt">Update All Providers</button>
                <span id="lblUMsg"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am trying to change the `li` background when hovered over `.content` div with the following which isn't working:

```
$('body').on("mouseenter", ".content", function (e) {
    $(this).prevAll("li").css("background", "#FF0000");
});
$('body').on("mouseleave", ".content", function (e) {
    $(this).closest("ul li").css("background", "#FF0000");
});
```

How can I change the background color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it without jQuery is to add a container element (or use an existing one, which there may well be), and then change your existing `a:hover` selector to:

```
.container:hover .tabs a {}
```

Demo:

```css
.tabs {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
.tabs li {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 -15px 0 0;
}
.tabs a {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0 40px;
    height: 0;
    line-height: 30px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    border-right: 30px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 30px solid #3D3D3D;
    border-bottom-color: #777\9;
    opacity: .3;
    filter: alpha(opacity=30);
}
.container:hover .tabs a { /* This is the one I changed */
    border-bottom-color: #2ac7e1;
    opacity: 1;
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
}
 .content {
    background: #CCC;
    border-top: 2px solid #00539B;
    padding: 2em;
    min-height: 115px;
}
.content h2, .content h3, .content h4, .content p {
    margin: 0 0 15px 0;
    color: #00539B;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <ul class="tabs">
        <li><a href="">Filter Options</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="content">
     <h4>Filter by a provider name to update the individual profile</h4>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me. I am thinking because I have them inside an UpdatePanel. :/

Comment: @SiKni8 If you give your existing div with inline styles a class of `container`, it should work.

Comment: @TyleH Silly me. Thank you. `content` `container` looked almost similar and didn't even see it. That worked for me like a charm. Thank you. +1 and Accept!

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `prev()`

```
$('body').on("mouseenter", ".content", function (e) {
    $(this).prev().find('li').css("background", "#FF0000");
});
```

Or `prevAll()` in following format

```
$('body').on("mouseleave", ".content", function (e) {
    $(this).prevAll("ul").first().find('li').css("background", "#FF0000");
});
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/5y6vc6xw/ (I want to achieve the hover function over the LI) Pretty much when I hover over the LI, the color changes to sky blue. I want the same function to work when I hover over `content`. +1 by the way for getting it to work almost.

Comment: Thank you but I don't want it to be a rectangle. Just the `a` when you hover over the `li a`. Hover over `Step #2`. I want the same when hovered over 'content' DIV

Comment: I wonder why the JSfiddle is showing differently from mine. Can you please add a screenshot of what you see when you hover over `content`?

Comment: Thank you for the Fiddle. I think the CSS is a better option as it is not relied on a script.

Comment: @SiKni8 : of course css solution will be better n fastr :)

Comment: I +1 your answer because it worked as well if anyone else wants to use it.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to change just the previous element of ".content" why target the body? Just target what you are trying to change.

Example

```
   $(".content").hover(function(){
     $(this).css( "background-color", "#FF0000" );
    });

  $(".tabs li").hover(function(){
     $(this).css( "background-color", "#FF0000" );
    });
```

Answer Revised!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/5y6vc6xw/ (I want to achieve the hover function over the LI) Pretty much when I hover over the LI, the color changes to sky blue. I want the same function to work when I hover over `content`. +1 by the way for getting it to work almost.

Comment: Check out the edited answer. Thanks for your correction!

Comment: Thank you but I don't want it to be a rectangle. Just the `a` when you hover over the `li a`. Hover over `Step #2`. I want the same when hovered over 'content' DIV